# jenkins ansible-plugin can't find ansible role

Tags: jenkins, ansible

hope you guys are doing great .
i have a problem running a playbook using ansible plugin in jenkins
when i run the build it gives me this error :

```
ansible-demo] $ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ansible-demo/ansible-openshift.yaml -f 5
ERROR! the role 'ansible.kubernetes-modules' was not found in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ansible-demo/roles:/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ansible-demo

The error appears to be in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ansible-demo/ansible-openshift.yaml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - role: ansible.kubernetes-modules
      ^ here
FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:232)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
ERROR: Ansible playbook execution failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

here is my yaml file that i use to deploy in openshift cluster

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become: yes
  become_user: oassaghir
  roles:
    - role: ansible.kubernetes-modules

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:
  - name: Try to login to Okd cluster
    k8s_auth:
      host: https://127.0.0.1:8443
      username: developer
      password: ****
      validate_certs: no
    register: k8s_auth_result

  - name: deploy hello-world pod
    k8s:
      state: present
      apply: yes
      namespace: myproject
      host: https://127.0.0.1:8443
      api_key: "{{ k8s_auth_result.k8s_auth.api_key }}"
      validate_certs: no
      definition:
        apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: hello-openshift
          labels:
            name: hello-openshift
        spec:
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: hello-openshift
          replicas: 1
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                app: hello-openshift
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: hello-openshift
                image: openshift/hello-openshift
                ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
                resources:
                  requests:
                    cpu: 300m
                    memory: 64Mi
                  limits:
                    cpu: 600m
                    memory: 128Mi
```

when i run the code in my machine it works but using jenkins no

in my mahcine :

```
[oassaghir@openshift ansible-demo]$ sudo ansible-playbook ansible-openshift.yaml

PLAY [127.0.0.1] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [ansible.kubernetes-modules : Install latest openshift client] ***********************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Try to login to Okd cluster] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [deploy hello-world pod] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

can someone help plz !

Comment: Did you retrieve the role(s) in your pipeline prior to invoking the plugin?

Comment: im sorry but im new at this can you please provide more details !